# Does Spark run with OpenJ9 and Java 8?

Tags: java, apache-spark, adoptopenjdk, openj9

Is Spark functional for use with **Java 8 + OpenJ9**?

I found a pull request for version **3.0.0** but it was not very clear to me the consequences of running without this pull request. I am currently using version **2.3.0**.

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/24308

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27397

Comment: Based on the pull request, you might get a `NoClassDefFoundError` depending on whether you use some specific things (like Kerberos).

Comment: In my case I am using JDBC functionality to import data from an external data source. It is working without errors so far. [ref-spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I know, there's no functional problem. The pull request simply allows the SizeEstimator to correctly determine whether an OpenJ9 JVM is using compressed references. Correctly determining that compressed references are used "just" provides a performance boost.